# Django query to get three objects at a time

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a page in my application that list three news articles, and there are navigation buttons on the bottom of the page to get the next three, or previous three news articles.

I am trying to think of a query that would solve that, but I don't want to use `Django Paginator`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is Django's paginator not suitable?

Comment: Its suitable, however attempting this for so long before discovering paginator, I guess curiosity has gotten the better of me, and Im wondering if its even possible with just object managers.

Comment: Even easier would be to use a [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview), then you're entire view code (including pagination) would be about 5 lines (minimum)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can slice querysets to limit the number of results.

```
article = Article.objects.all()[:3]  # first three articles

article = Article.objects.all()[3:6]  # second three articles
```

On your site, you'll want a way to track which page you are on so that you can slice the queryset correctly, and display links to previous and next pages. You can implement this yourself if you want, but it would be easier to use the Django paginator, that does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you don't want to use `Django Paginator` for that, however, if the reason behind it is that you didn't bother to figure it out I suggest give it another try since the scenario you are describing is a classic use of the `Paginator` class.

From the [`pagination`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/) documentation, check out this example:

Define your view function:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts import render

def listing(request):
    article_list = Articles.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(article_list, 3) # Show 3 articles per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        articles = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        articles = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'list.html', {'articles': articles})
```

And the HTML form:

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {# Each "article" is a Article model object. #}
    {{ article.full_name|upper }}<br />
    ...
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if articles.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ articles.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ articles.number }} of {{ articles.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if articles.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ articles.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```